# Including associated models to render json based on conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to figure out how to include an associated model for JSON I'm rendering, based on certain specifications. This is what I have so far:

```
render json: @colleges, include: :sports
```

`@colleges` is a collection of colleges, and all associated sports are included.

However, I want to be able to include another associated model *only if it belongs to the current user*.

So for instance, I can get favorites that belong to a college and a user with `Favorite.where(college: @college).where(user: current_user)`.

Is there a way to include favorites that belong to the current_user and each college to this render?

Comment: Lets assume the user is loggedin, does this return proper result? `@colleges.joins(:favorite).where(user: current_user)`

Comment: This gives me the proper result, but I'd like to render all colleges regardless of whether or not a user favorite is associated with it. But I want to include the associated favorite if it exists. So the json would look something like `{college: {name: 'foo', location: 'bar', sports: {name: 'basketball'}}` if the user favorite does not exist. If it does exist, it would look something like `{college: {name: 'foo', location: 'bar', sports: {name: 'basketball'}, favorites: {user_id: 45}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using conditional scopes:

In your model

```
scope :favorite_for, -> (user) { joins(:favorite).where(user: current_user) if user }
```

In your controller

```
@colleges = College.favorite_for(current_user).all # or where() or whatever you like..
```

Hope it helps..